# Wordpress WP-API Failed to run

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

I'm installing a clean wordpress site and trying to learn on how WP-API works. i read the documentation on http://v2.wp-api.org .. it said "..  Want to get your site’s posts? Simply send a GET request to /wp-json/wp/v2/posts .."

So i test on a clean install of wordpress:
http://unityofwomen.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

But there's error "rest_no_route".. 
do i miss something ? accessing http://unityofwomen.com/wp-json/ has result though..

Answer (score 0):

Got a confirmation from the author that Wordpress has embed wp-json into the core but not the route.. so we need to install the routes ourself.

But i'm still wondering why WP not include the base route into the core